# Service programming in C

Tags: c, bash, service, daemon, nohup

I'm trying to run my program multiple times with different arguments in background. my program runs like `./program /var/log/apache2/access.log`, `./program /var/log/apache2/access.log` etc. I'm doing it with script that uses nohup but it executes only one of them. But it's making seperate pids. Can i make it in one pid. I tried [this](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html) but when i execute with it it doesn't do anything. No pid, nothing. So can i execute my program several times under one pid ?. Why is my script executing only one of plenty?
Here's my script:

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) <= 0 ))
then
    while read line
    do
        nohup ./gsm_alarm $line </dev/null &>/dev/null &
        echo $line
    done < $filename
fi
```

it uses conf file that saves arguments like:

```
syslog.conf /var/log/syslog
authlog.conf /var/log/auth.log
accesslog.conf /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Here's daemon skeleton i used(but failed):

```
static void skeleton_daemon()
{
/* Our process ID and Session ID */
    pid_t pid, sid;

    /* Fork off the parent process */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* If we got a good PID, then
       we can exit the parent process. */
    if (pid > 0) {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    /* Change the file mode mask */
    umask(0);

    /* Open any logs here */        

    /* Create a new SID for the child process */
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) {
            /* Log the failure */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    /* Change the current working directory */
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
            /* Log the failure */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    /* Open the log file */
    // openlog ("gsm_alarm", LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON);
    // printf("OPENED\n");
}
```

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.  For instance, #include <sys/types.h> is missing so 'pid_t' is not defined.  Both #include <sys/types.h> and #include <sys/stat.h> are missing, so umask() is not defined.  parameter 'argc' is not used, so the compiler raises a warning about that too.  Suggest compile with warnings enabled, (for gcc, as a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' )

Comment: @user3629249 yeah it's not a full source code, it's just a part of daemon process.

Comment: when code has an execution time problem, the posted code needs to be a fully compilable/executable that demonstrates the problem.  The posted code is not compilable, so how are we to debug the run time problem?

Comment: You can not run a program several times under one pid. A program is identified by its pid.

Comment: You can start debugging with a shellscript `gsm_alarm`, and see how your mainscript works: `sleep 5; echo "$(date): $*" > /tmp/gsmdebug.$$` and use something like `nohup ./gsm_alarm $line >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: A *process* is identified by a PID, not a program.  You can run a program several times under the same pid by using one of the "exec" family.  From bash that's using `exec` and from C for example `execve()`.  This will replace the current program with another.  Note that there can be no return from a successful "exec", so each program must manage running the next.